# opencv.js properties&methods are not accessible from a function

Tags: javascript, opencv

I have the following simple `html` file using the hosted opencv.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script
      async
      src="https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js"
      onload="onOpenCvLoaded();"
      type="text/javascript"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      function onOpenCvLoaded() {
        console.log(cv);
        test(cv);
      }
      function test() {
        console.log(new cv.Mat());
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expect to see a new Mat instance in the console, but instead I got:

```
Uncaught TypeError: cv.Mat is not a constructor
    at test (test.html:18)
    at onOpenCvLoaded (test.html:15)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onload (test.html:9)
test    @   test.html:18
onOpenCvLoaded  @   test.html:15
onload  @   test.html:9
```

However `new cv.Mat()` works if I type in the console directly. What's going inside, and how can I make new cv.Mat() work inside the `test` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the link which provided the answer: https://dev.to/kjunichi/requireopencvjs-is-not-enough-for-using-opencvjs-8ff

Execute a function when `cv` is completely initialized:

```
cv['onRuntimeInitialized']=()=>{
          let mat = new cv.Mat();
          console.log(mat.size());
          mat.delete();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use an onload function on loading your opencv.js file like this `function onLoad(){
onRuntimeinitialized = main;`

Your main function will be excecuted when opencv is ready